# MySQL question about getting concret columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database that contains information like this:

activity: R1A1, R1A2, R1A2_2

My problem is where I'm trying to get all the activities that do not contain the second part (_2).

I'm trying this query: `SELECT activity FROM table_name WHERE activity NOT LIKE '%_2'` but I'm getting only the activity R1A1. This is because R1A2 contains a number two on its name. How can I solve it? What is the correct query to do that? I want to get all the activities without _2 or something like that on its name.

If I do in an inverse method (`SELECT activity FROM table_name WHERE activity NOT LIKE 'R1%'` I get the correct results.

How can I get what I need? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

in MYSQL, the underscore is a wildcard, much like the `%` except it matches one character. You can escape it with `\` to get the literal.

Here is the correct query:

```
SELECT activity FROM table_name WHERE activity NOT LIKE '%\_2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The underscore in `LIKE` is a wildcard that matches any character.  You can escape it.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT activity
FROM table_name
WHERE activity NOT LIKE '%$_2' ESCAPE '$';
```